# SHA1 Using php and .net

Tags: php, .net, sha1

Can u pls help me for the below issue.

I have sha1 value in mssql table (Password is encrypted using algorithm SHA1 which provided in Microsoft .Net library) .

I created one php application, in that i need to compare these encrypted value.

Thanks

Comment: Hi josh, Lynn is currently out. Can you try again in an hour or two? ;P

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to compare a user provided password with the hashed value from the database. In that case, just use the native php sha1 function:

```
if($hashedPasswordFromDB == sha1($plainUserProvidedPassword)) {
    echo "Approved!";
}
else {
    echo "Denied!";
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more debug info? i.e. The output of sha1($plainUserProvidedPassword) and the output of $hashedPasswordFromDB?